# Unable to load an image in sub folder present in the working directory- Google maps marker icon

Tags: asp.net, google-maps-api-3, path, google-maps-markers

A simple issue but unable to find a solution.

I have some image files that I placed in a subfolder called **icons** in my working directory in my ASP.NET website. I want to set an image during initialization to the markers on my Google map. But this isn't working. I have tried-

```
var marker= new google.maps.Marker({icon:'E:\cdeez\Sites\googletest 5\icons\busballon.png', position:pos,map:map});
```

It gives an error:

> Not allowed to load local resource: file:///E:/cdeezSitesgoogletest%205icons%08usballon.png

However there is no problem if I place the image in the working directory. I guess giving the absolute path is not the right way too. So what is the right way in the above case.(Just a reminder- the above code will be in the **aspx** file).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [MarkerOptions docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MarkerOptions), the icon should be a URL. However local files (embedded with `file:///`) tend to be ignored by browsers if the website is served over http - and I think that is what is happening in your case.

I would suggest to try out the following steps:

- try using a relative path, e.g `icon: "/icons/busballon.png"`
- try using a http path to your file, e.g. `icon: "http://yoursite.com/icons/busballon.png"`